# ng-disabled is not disabling a button in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why does the Button is not disable?

```js
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', []);

mainApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.form = {
        login: ''
    };
});
```

```html
<form ng-controller="LoginAppCtrl as lc" ng-app="MTApp">
  <div class="login">
    <h1>LOG IN</h1> 
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>User Name :</div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="tbUserName" required ng-model="lc.request.user">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>Password :</div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="tbPassword" required ng-model="lc.request.password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button ng-click="lc.submitRequest()" ng-disabled="lc.request.user == '' || lc.request.password == '' ">Sign In</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I'm new in Angular JS and I am trying to make a simple login form, that if login success will be shown other form, and if not, login form will be stayed.
Can anyone help me? I need the basic tutorials.

Comment: where is the code of `LoginAppCtrl` add code of it..

Comment: Still not working in my app

http://jsfiddle.net/1urcz8r3/

Moreover where do I set which form will be shown when success login and that the login form will stay in failure?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have several mistakes in your code:

**The first one** is that you're declaring your module as main app: `angular.module('mainApp', []);` but you are doing `ng-app="MTApp"`. You need to use the app that you declared, meaning it needs to be `ng-app="mainApp"`.

Same goes for the controller declaration and `ng-controller`, it needs to be the same.

**Second issue** is that if `request` is an object, you should initiate it at your controller:

```
$scope.request = {};
```

**Third issue** is that you need to check for `undefined` as well, not just an empty string:

```
ng-disabled="!request.user || !request.password"
```

Look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nc4yxcez/) for a complete code & HTML.

Comment: I had done as you wrote.

main.js
 var MEControllers = angular.module('MEControllers',[]);
 MEControllers.controller('LoginAppCtrl', function ($scope) {
     $scope.form = {
         login: ''
     };
     $scope.request = {};
 });

Comment: Still not working in my app

http://jsfiddle.net/1urcz8r3/

Moreover where do I set which form will be shown when success login and that the login form will stay in failure?

Thanks

Comment: @userit1985 You declared 2 ng-apps there instead of one, and you have dependency issues which cause errors and therefore nothing works.

Comment: @userit1985 And also you did not declare AngularJS on the fiddle itself on the top left corner. Compare to my fiddle.

Comment: So how should I wrote my Login form using
 function LoginAppCtrl($scope, $http,utilities,$location) {?

Comment: @userit1985 It's ok to use those dependencies, but it just doesn't work in that fiddler you used.

Answer (score 1):

The disabling button functionality can be accomplished in two ways

1) Based on values in the text boxes, with out relating to controller object.
Give some name to form element like

```
<form name='form1'>
  <div>
    <div>User Name :</div>
      <input type="text" name="tbUserName" required ng-model="lc.request.user">
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Password :</div>
      <input type="text" name="tbPassword" required ng-model="lc.request.password">
  </div>
  <div>
    <button ng-disabled="form1.$invalid">Sign In</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

2) Based on Object defined in the controller.

If you have an object in your controller say 
      `$scope.user = {name:'', password:''}`
then at input boxes you can use 
    `ng-model='user.name'` and `ng-model = 'user.password'`
At the submit button, you can use 
`ng-disabled=" user.name === '' || user.password === '' "`
Then also, the submit button will be disabled unless you fill those two text boxes.

```
<form>
  <div>
    <div>User Name :</div>
      <input type="text" name="tbUserName" required ng-model="user.name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Password :</div>
      <input type="text" name="tbPassword" required ng-model="user.password">
  </div>
  <div>
    <button ng-disabled="user.name==='' || user.password===''">Sign In</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

And the controller should have object defined

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.user = {name:'',password:''};
});
```

Is this you are expecting?